# Set up alerting for pod evictions in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, stackdriver, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm encountering a situation where pods are occasionally getting evicted after running out of memory.  Is there any way to set up some kind of alerting where I can be notified when this happens?

As it is, Kubernetes keeps doing its job and re-creating pods after the old ones are removed, and it's often hours or days before I'm made aware that a problem exists at all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

GKE exports Kubernetes Events (`kubectl get events`) to Stackdriver Logging, to the "GKE Cluster Operations" table:
[image]

Next, write a query specifically targeting evictions (the query I pasted below might not be accurate):

[image]

Then click "CREATE METRIC" button.

This will create a Log-based Metric. On the left sidebar, click "Logs-based metrics" and click the "Create alert from metric" option on the context menu of this metric:

[image]

Next, you'll be taken to Stackdriver Alerting portal. You can set up alerts there based on thresholds etc.

Comment: This is perfect - thank you so much!  I didn't know that you could create log alert metrics directly from stackdriver like that.  I really appreciate you taking the time to create this detailed answer.